# Unable to pay even the minimum payment on credit card

Tags: united-states, canada, credit-card, bankruptcy

I was in USA for last 10 years, and I am not able to repay the credit-card payment, not even the minimum payment due. I was paying the minimum payment due before, but as I do not have a job anymore I am unable to pay even that now.

I have all the intention to pay my credit card bills, however my questions are :

1. Can they come to my Home Country CANADA, and ask for payment ?
2. What should I do ?
3. Should I call the bank about my current situation ? Will this work ?

Comment: Nice constructive answer below. I might only add that the original question is a classic example of the dangers of credit cards. Also, if one is an able reasonably healthy adult, there is virtually no excuse for not having a job for an extended period in today's economy, whether in the U.S. or Canada. I recommend finding A job - ANY job - asap, downsizing to absolute bare essentials (cheapest rent close to work etc) for a period of about 6 months to a year. You will be surprised how much you will be able to save and pay off, to move closer to financial independence. Lessons learned! Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

Banks are international these days. So are collection agencies. Assume they can prosecute in Canada.

Your best bet, I think, is to talk to the bank ASAP, before they write you off as a bad debt. You aren't the only person to lose a job. If you haven't been running the card up to its maximum to keep yourself afloat -- if you're really just left with a normal balance -- you may be able to talk them into letting you make some token payment for a few months while you get at least enough of a temp job to feed yourself and start making larger payments to them. Convince them that you *will* pay it off, so it's better for them to carry you than to sell your account at a partial loss.

Also, it's time to swallow your pride and ask relatives if they could help you cover that minimum payment. Offer to pay *them* interest on the loan they make to you -- they may turn you down, but making it a business transaction saves face for everyone and makes destroying the relationship less likely.

(I've been on the other side of a "help, I'm out of work and need to cover expenses" loan -- and it really was a loan, legal paperwork and me paying tax on the interest income and all, though I insisted on charging a minimal interest rate.)

Comment: Agree with @keshlam and I did this for my now wife. Now we're in a better spot in terms of credit and also were able to repay my friend (whom I asked) with a nominal interest (from the hefty interest that we ended up saving by not paying high APRs).

Answer (score 2):

How long has this situation going on?

If you've been like this for more than 2 years and have no real possibilities to pay it off in the net 10 year, you should consider bankruptcy. Many people will do better with a fresh start that being stuck in this situation forever.

Sure, your credit score will suffer and you may not be able to get a credit card in a while, but that may be a blessing in disguise.

Best of luck!